# Reading serial port faster

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, embedded, usb

I have a computer software that sends RGB color codes to Arduino using USB. It works fine when they are sent slowly but when tens of them are sent every second it freaks out. What I think happens is that the Arduino serial buffer fills out so quickly that the processor can't handle it the way I'm reading it.

```
#define INPUT_SIZE 11

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    char input[INPUT_SIZE + 1];
    byte size = Serial.readBytes(input, INPUT_SIZE);
    input[size] = 0;

    int channelNumber = 0;

    char* channel = strtok(input, " ");
    while(channel != 0) {
      color[channelNumber] = atoi(channel);

      channel = strtok(0, " ");
      channelNumber++;
    }

    setColor(color);
  }
}
```

For example the computer might send `255 0 123` where the numbers are separated by space. This works fine when the sending interval is slow enough or the buffer is always filled with only one color code, for example `255 255 255` which is 11 bytes (`INPUT_SIZE`). However if a color code is not 11 bytes long and a second code is sent immediately, the code still reads 11 bytes from the serial buffer and starts combining the colors and messes them up. How do I avoid this but keep it as efficient as possible?

Comment: You mean bytes, not bits. But if the data you intend to read isn't always 11 bytes long, you can't just read 11 bytes and expect everything to work. If the first message is, let's say, "1 2 3" and the second one is "12 3 4", the data present in the input will be "1 2 312 3 4". It seems to me to be impossible to know if it means "1 2 3" followed by "12 3 4", or if it means "1 2 31" followed by "2 3 4"? Can you change the format, for example to send the three bytes as binary bytes, and not converted to text?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPadron-McCarthy! I changed the program on the computer to send HEX color codes. Now I always receive six bytes which I then need to convert back to RGB. http://pastebin.com/JL31zwWQ

Comment: I don't understand how it is 6 bytes? You were supposed to send 1 byte for every channel, which makes three. Also, use a struct to map the raw input to your formatted version. See my post below.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a matter of reading the serial port faster, it is a matter of not reading a fixed block of 11 characters when the input data has variable length.

You are telling it to read until 11 characters are received or the timeout occurs, but if the first group is fewer than 11 characters, and a second group follows immediately there will be no timeout, and you will partially read the second group. You seem to understand that, so I am not sure how you conclude that "reading faster" will help.

Using your existing data encoding of ASCII decimal space delimited triplets, one solution would be to read the input one character at a time until the entire triplet were read, however you could more simply use the Arduino `ReadBytesUntil()` function:

```
#define INPUT_SIZE 3

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        char rgb_str[3][INPUT_SIZE+1] = {{0},{0},{0}};

        Serial.readBytesUntil( " ", rgb_str[0], INPUT_SIZE );
        Serial.readBytesUntil( " ", rgb_str[1], INPUT_SIZE );
        Serial.readBytesUntil( " ", rgb_str[2], INPUT_SIZE );

        for( int channelNumber = 0; channelNumber < 3; channelNumber++)
        {
            color[channelNumber] = atoi(channel);
        }

        setColor(color);
    }
}
```

Note that this solution does not require the somewhat heavyweight `strtok()` processing since the `Stream` class has done the delimiting work for you.

However there is a simpler and even more efficient solution. In your solution you are sending ASCII decimal strings then requiring the Arduino to spend CPU cycles needlessly extracting the fields and converting to integer values, when you could simply send the byte values directly - leaving if necessary the vastly more powerful PC to do any necessary processing to pack the data thus.  Then the code might be simply:

```
void loop()
{
    if( Serial.available() )
    {
        for( int channelNumber = 0; channelNumber < 3; channelNumber++)
        {
            color[channelNumber] = Serial.Read() ;
        }

        setColor(color);
    }
}
```

Note that I have not tested any of above code, and the Arduino documentation is lacking in some cases with respect to descriptions of return values for example.  You may need to tweak the code somewhat.

Neither of the above solve the synchronisation problem - i.e. when the colour values are streaming, how do you know which is the start of an RGB triplet?  You have to rely on getting the first field value and maintaining count and sync thereafter - which is fine until perhaps the Arduino is started after data stream starts, or is reset, or the PC process is terminated and restarted asynchronously.   However that was a problem too with your original implementation, so perhaps a problem to be dealt with elsewhere.

Comment: How do I send the color in three bytes?

Comment: @MikkoP : One byte of reach of the R,G,B components.  A byte can represent the values 0 to 255.  Your serial comms will need to be configured for 8 data but frames (normally the default in any case)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with @Thomas Padron-McCarthy. Sending character string instead of a byte array(11 bytes instead of 3 bytes, and the parsing process) is would<strike>simply</strike> be waste of resources. On the other hand, the approach you should follow depends on your sender:

- Is it periodic or not
- Is is fixed size or not

If it's periodic you can check in the time period of the messages. If not, you need to check the messages before the buffer is full.
**If you think printable encoding is not suitable for you somehow;** In any case i would add an checksum to the message. Let's say you have fixed size message structure:

```
typedef struct MyMessage
{
    // unsigned char id; // id of a message maybe?
    unsigned char colors[3]; // or unsigned char r,g,b; //maybe
    unsigned char checksum; // more than one byte could be a more powerful checksum
};

unsigned char calcCheckSum(struct MyMessage msg)
{
    //...
}

unsigned int validateCheckSum(struct MyMessage msg)
{
    //...
    if(valid)
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}
```

Now, you should check every 4 byte (the size of MyMessage) in a sliding window fashion if it is valid or not:

```
 void findMessages( )
 {
     struct MyMessage* msg;
     byte size = Serial.readBytes(input, INPUT_SIZE);
     byte msgSize = sizeof(struct MyMessage);
     for(int i = 0; i+msgSize <= size; i++)
     {
         msg = (struct MyMessage*) input[i];
         if(validateCheckSum(msg))
         {// found a message
             processMessage(msg);
         }
         else
         {
             //discard this byte, it's a part of a corrupted msg (you are too late to process this one maybe)
         }
     }
 }
```

If It's not a fixed size, it gets complicated. But i'm guessing you don't need to hear that for this case.

**EDIT (2)** 
I've striked out this edit upon comments.
<strike>One last thing, i would use a circular buffer. First add the received bytes into the buffer, then check the bytes in that buffer.</strike>

**EDIT (3)**
I gave thought on comments. I see the point of printable encoded messages. I guess my problem is working in a military company. We don't have printable encoded "fire" arguments here :) There are a lot of messages come and go all the time and decoding/encoding printable encoded messages would be waste of time. Also we use hardwares which usually has very small messages with bitfields. I accept that it could be more easy to examine/understand a printable message.

Hope it helps,
Gokhan.

Comment: The Arduino Serial class is already buffered and interrupt driven, and since there is no multi-threading, a secondary buffer would serve no purpose.  +1 for addressing the synchronisation issue.

Comment: I've never used or even seen and ardunio :) Thanks for the rectification.

Comment: Character strings are simpler for debugging and if performance is not the critical factor, they may well be the better choice.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I don't agree with you, If you are not sending a text as message. I've never seen sending a character array instead of structured message is a better choice.

Comment: @FUZxxl : The data being "eye-legible"may make debugging easier, but in this case is the actual cause of the bug (the attempt to process variable length data as if it were fixed length).  It highlights the biggest problem with Arduino - no debugger with on-chip debug support.  Watching byte variables in a debugger would be trivial.  In this case using debug printing output at the Arduino end would be preferable to consuming the channel bandwidth unnecessarily.

Comment: The problem here isn't printable encoding, it's just poorly thought out code.  The advantage of printable encoding is not only debug legibility, but even more so the ease of inserting **terminators** to indicate an end-of-message.  A newline handles that very easily.  Trying to insert framing into 3-byte groups is a pain - unless you are willing to declare some byte value illegal in data in order to be able to use it as a message header or terminator, you'll end up having to escape the value you give that special meaning to any time it occurs as a data value.

Answer (score 0):

If faster is really what you want....this is little far fetched.

The fastest way I can think of to meet your needs and provide synchronization is by sending a byte for each color and changing the parity bit in a defined way assuming you can read the parity and bytes value of the character with wrong parity.

You will have to deal with the changing parity and most of the characters will not be human readable, but it's gotta be one of the fastest ways to send three bytes of data.